# How to Install Php5.6 in amazon linux

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to install php 5.6 on Amazon linux using the following command:

```
$ yum install php56
No package php56 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Is there a repository I need to add in order to do this? I've searched for this but couldn't find any source. I'd also like to know which Apache versions work with this version of php?

Comment: `yum install php56w`

Comment: Clone the PHP repository, check the `5.6` branch and build it from source.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AWS has not yet packaged php 5.6. You need to install php 5.5 from the ALAMI repositories, or build 5.6 from source.

To list the available 5.5 packages use `yum search php55`

The `php55` is the base package, but you may need others listed as well.

When 5.6 is ready, you'll be able to find it with
`yum search php56`

You can find information on building the source at [php.net](http://php.net), specifically [Installation on Unix Systems / Apache 2.x on Unix Systems](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)

Comment: Now AWS has packaged php 5.6

Comment: What are the ALAMI repositories?

Comment: @manan in which repo it's available? I want to migrate my php56 application from amazon linux1 to amazonlinux2. and don't want to go with the ius-release*.rpm.

Comment: @mahendrarathod php56 was already end of life or close when Amazon Linux 2 came out, so I doubt it's in the base packages. I don't have an AL2 machine handy, but you can try Extras to see if they've packaged it for you https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#extras-library

Comment: @mahendrarathod I just checked and looks like it's not available in AL2, you are on your own to build from source. AL2 only has php7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 8.0 available. Oddly it seems the default `php` package is 5.4 on Amazon Linux 2 (without using extras).

Answer (score 111):

Below are the steps I have used to update PHP version from 5.3 to 5.6 in Amazon Linux

Steps (Use **sudo** only if required)

1) Remove OLD Apache

```
sudo service httpd stop
sudo yum erase httpd httpd-tools apr apr-util
```

2) Remove OLD PHP

```
sudo yum remove php-*
```

3) Install PHP 5.6 (Apache 2.4 will be automatically installed with this)

```
sudo yum install php56
```

4) Make sure all the required PHP extensions are installed

```
yum list installed | grep php
```

5) If not then install them using

```
sudo yum install php56-xml php56-xmlrpc php56-soap php56-gd
```

6) To list the other available php extensions

```
yum search php56
```

7) PHP 5.6 MySQL extension (Assume you have already installed MySQL)

```
sudo yum install php56-mysqlnd
```

(NOTE: it is not php56-mysql)

8) Start / Restart Apache

```
sudo service httpd start
sudo service httpd restart
```

9) Check the version

```
php -v
httpd -v
```

Comment: Great answer. I combined it with this: http://brianshim.com/webtricks/update-amazon-ami-php5-3-to-php5-4/

Comment: This is realy very helpful answer and it saved me alot of time .Thanks Rijas for that

Comment: i searched far to long for this answer! Thank you! Works very well!

Comment: For this: `Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64`   
I had to `sudo yum remove httpd-tools-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64` first and then `sudo yum install -y httpd24 php56`

Comment: be aware that your httpd.conf file may get overwritten.  Did not occur to me to back it up, had to recreate from scratch for multiple sites.

Comment: Hell yeah worked nicely

Answer (score 10):

Just to mantain update the answers, 
I tryed the proposed solution and didn't work.

Quite hard to install 5.6

I found the right command nowaday to install 7.2 is

```
amazon-linux-extras install php7.2
```

it install and upgrade everything without complications.

Comment: To whoever flagged this as "not an answer", this appears to be offering an alternative solution to the original question, not actually a follow-up question. Hence, it is actually an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo yum -y update

sudo yum install –y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

sudo wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo wget https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm

sudo rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm

sudo yum -y update
```

When you install the package you'll need to add a u to the end of php56. Here is an example of some packages you could install.

```
sudo yum -y install php56u php56u-opcache php56u-xml \
  php56u-mcrypt php56u-gd php56u-devel php56u-mysql \
  php56u-intl php56u-mbstring php56u-bcmath php56u-soap
```

Answer (score 1):

Successfully installed php56 and required php-module on amazonlinux2 with the repo epo.ius.io.

```
 sudo yum -y update
    sudo yum install –y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
    wget https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm
    sudo rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm
    sudo yum -y update
    sudo yum install --enablerepo=ius-archive php56u php56u-opcache php56u-xml php56u-mcrypt php56u-gd php56u-devel php56u-mysql php56u-intl php56u-mbstring php56u-bcmath php56u-soap
```

Check PHP version with below command

```
[root@ip-10-10-1-47 ~]# php -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Jan 11 2019 10:27:04) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

To install php module

```
yum install --enablerepo=ius-archive php56u-{Module Name}
```

Validate the module name

```
php -m
php -m | grep {Module Name}
example to check php yaml module
php -m | grep  yaml
```

Reference URL : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=284157

Answer (score 0):

**Additional part from @Daniele post for resloving this problem.**

This is more help than question, but to help other with problem which I had in my case. I need to install Wordpress site on EC2, but when I tried to run it with public IP address, it was problem. I tried to install php 5.6, but it was not possible.

I find solution to install php 7.2, using command:

```
**amazon-linux-extras install php7.2**
```

TO check that is really version php 7.2, use:

```
php -version  or   php -v
```

After this, you need to stop apache service, command for stop is:

```
service httpd stop
```

Start again apache service:

```
service httpd start
```

In your AWS console, go to Instance, find public IP address, copy and open in browser. You should see the WordPress page. You can install WordPress in Advanced part (bootstraping), when you create EC2 instance.