# Not working when trying to install phpmyadmin on Amazon AWS Linux?

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to install phpmyadmin through Bitvise SSH Client.

What I did on SSH client terminal console was:

```
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.5.4.1/phpMyAdmin-4.5.4.1-all-languages.zip 
unzip phpMyAdmin-4.5.4.1-all-languages.zip
mv phpMyAdmin-4.5.4.1-all-languages /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin
rm phpMyAdmin-4.5.4.1-all-languages.zip 

egrep ‘User|Group’ /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

> Here it came out an eoor about '|Group***, I ignored it and kept doing the next step'

```
useradd phpmydmin
passwd phpmyadmin
cd /var/www/html
chown –R phpmyadmin.apache phpMyAdmin/ 
cd phpMyAdmin
mkdir config
cp config.sample.inc.php config/config.inc.php
chown –R phpmyadmin.apache config/
chmod –R o+rw config/ 
service httpd restart
```

It didn't work...Then I followed the steps online that I found on
http://tecadmin.net/setup-phpmyadmin-on-linux-using-source/.

I didn't know how to add the following below either:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
</Directory>

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin"
```

> Could someone help me with it please? &

```
Why allowing from 192.168.1.0/24? which IP is this?
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Those are both settings for your webserver. Assuming you are using apache, you would need to modify the /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf file. Note that depending on the distribution, I'm not sure what amazon aws uses, this may be under /etc/apache or /etc/apache2 instead. You basically need to create/edit that file per the instructions.

Comment: if mysql is denied: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845715/1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, and I am having trouble understanding what you need, honestly. It looks like you cannot edit that configuration file. Well, if that's the problem, you just need to follow the following instructions.

> *Create a new apache configuration file for phpMyAdmin at
>   `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` and add following settings there.*

To do that, you just need to open a text editor (*nano* is my favorite) with

`sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`

We need root permissions to operate in the /etc folder, that's why we use `sudo`. Edit the file as required, and save with `Ctrl+O`. Then, quit nano with `Ctrl+X`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have found an answer for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your replies!

I have found a perfect answer in this link:

> https://superuser.com/questions/291230/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-linux-ec2-instance

Also if the page shows:

> "PHP 5.5+ is required"

Then look at this page:

> https://serverfault.com/questions/566527/update-php-with-yum-on-amazon-linux

or

> [How to Install Php5.6 in amazon linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206795/how-to-install-php5-6-in-amazon-linux/31602840#31602840)

Extra Error: The mbstring extension is missing,

do below:

> yum install php56-mbstring

and

> sudo service httpd restart

Great day to continue the AWS journey!

Good luck to every other one like me out there!

:-)

Comment: Useful Link 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648712/amazon-aws-filezilla-transfer-permission-denied

Comment: Useful Link 4: http://www.cloudcertification.training/how-to-install-wordpress-on-aws-using-the-cli/

Comment: Useful Link 5: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html

Comment: Useful Link 6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744863/connect-to-amazon-ec2-file-directory-using-filezilla-and-sftp

Answer (score -1):

I have found a perfect answer in this link

> http://howsolve.com/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-linux-ec2-instance/